# Constructing instance inside Scala Future's onComplete

Tags: scala, future

I have an existing code which returns an instance of certain type.

```
def myMethod(inputs) = {
   .....some calculations

   MyInstance(....)
}
```

I have to make a change in it now. Change calls some service which returns a Future of some value, which I need to use to update MyInstance.

```
def myMethod(inputs) = {
   .....some calculations

  val futureWithSomeValue = someexternalservice.getData(....)
  
  futureWithSomeValue.onComplete {
    case Success(value) => ....create MyInstance
    case Failure    => ....throw error
  }
}
```

But onComplete  returns Unit, and hence it breaks the code.

What is best way to do it without changing method signature?

Comment: I think that in this case you can use `map`: `future.map(MyInstance)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `myMethod` call a `Future` then `myMethod` must return a `Future`

Thus, as was said in the comments, you may rather use `map` instead of `onComplete` to produce a new `Future` with your instance and return that.

```scala
def myMethod(inputs): Future[MyInstance] = {
   // some calculations.

  val futureWithSomeValue = someexternalservice.getData(....)
  
  futureWithSomeValue.map { value =>
    MyInstance(...)
  }
```